# Views/Resources location for Silex Twig Library

Tags: php, twig, silex, composer-php

Normally, for a Silex project, I would have top-level directories like:

```
- app/
   - views/
- src/
- vendor/
- web/
```

Now, some of my classes may call `$app['twig']->render(...)` and it will pull out a view from the `app/views` folder.

**If I extract a library to be more reusable, across multiple projects, where should I keep its view files, and how do I instruct Twig to look there?**

The same question applies to graphics/stylesheets, etc which I would normally put in `web/`.

Surely they have to be within `vendor/my-lib` somewhere to allow Composer to cleanly install the files? Is there a common/best-practice way to do this?

**Update**
For reference, here's what I ended up doing:

```
<?php

// in my \Silex\ServiceProviderInterface ...

/**
 * @var \Twig_Environment $twig
 */
$twig = $app['twig'];

// Add the paths to our twig templates here
$fsLoader = new \Twig_Loader_Filesystem(array(
    __DIR__.'/views/'
));

$twig->setLoader(new \Twig_Loader_Chain(array($twig->getLoader(), $fsLoader)));
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I store the views under src/{Library}/{Class}/View/

I set the base path of Twig to the src

```
$app->register(new TwigServiceProvider(), array(
    'twig.path' => array(
        __DIR__ . '/../src/{Library}/'
    ),
    'twig.options' => array('cache' => false, 'strict_variables' => true)
));
```

and when calling render I pass in the path from that point

```
$app['twig']->render('{Class}/View/{twigfile}.html.twig',$data);
```

Comment: I like the organisation of that. Am I right in thinking you must register a path for each library in the bootstrap file, meaning a library can't register its own paths - you would have to `composer update` and add path when installing?

Comment: I use the autoloader to add the paths to my libs, in composer.json. e.g.
"autoload": {
        "psr-0": {"MyLibrary": "src/"}
}

Comment: Sorry, I meant the paths for each of the directories twig will look in when you call `render()`, can that be handled nicely?

Comment: Oh right I did it the way I did so that I could have files with the same name e.g index.twig.html in different View folders. If you wont have duplicates you could set the paths for each directory when you register TwigProvider.

Comment: My only issue, is that if somebody else wants to use my library, they have to configure the paths when really, they shouldn't have to know anything about the internal workings of my code. Maybe with access to `$app['twig']` there's a method to add a path - I'll have a look.

Comment: Have a look at Twig Loader in the API

Comment: Ah-ha! `Twig_Loader_Filesystem::addPath($path)` should do it. Thanks